# Prompt for consent every time with google auth, Cordova + ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm using this [Cordova GooglePlus Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) to sign-in with Google accounts. The issue is that I'm only able to get the refresh token in the first request. I would like to have this token every time.

I've read that adding `prompt=consent` setting would make it ask for consent in every login and I would be able to get the refresh token every time.

I just don't know where to add this setting to achieve this.

I'm signing in with:

```
    let opts = {
        scopes: "SCOPE1 SCOPE2",
        webClientId: WEBCLIENTID,
        offline: true
    }
    GooglePlus.login(opts)
```

Any one can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm getting the same issue

Comment: I am getting same any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the `authentication request`.

> You can prompt the user to re-authorize your app by adding the
>   prompt=consent parameter to the authentication request. When
>   prompt=consent is included, the consent screen is displayed every time
>   the user logs into your app. For this reason, include prompt=consent
>   only when necessary.

[**Authentication URI parameters - consent**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#prompt)

Comment: Hi @Sampath, since I'm using the plugin I don't think I've control over the request parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

this.afAuth.auth
        .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'}))
        .then((user) => {
          // your logic code here

```
    },(err) => {
      console.log("Error in auh service" + err);
     reject(err);
   })
```